# Using Kofax with C# for OCR

Tags: c#, ocr, kofax

In a C#.Net project we have OCR module to read paper forms and save details in SQL Server database. How can I use a Kofax product (may be Kofax Capture) for this? Please share your experience in using Kofax with C# for OCR processing.

Thanks,

Chatura

Answer (score 4):

Kofax Capture would end up probably being a complete replacement for your current .NET application.  It comes out of the box with OCR built in and a database export module, plus a host of other built-in and add-on features that can help clean up documents for recognition, export, import and other functionality.  The big things you would need to consider would be scanner compatibility, scan volume and hardware requirements.  I've used this software a lot and am pretty happy with it.

The most important thing to think about when trying to do OCR on forms is that they're all the same for a given "type" of form.  If the layout of all your forms varies widely from one instance to the next you will have problems unless you can account for all the different variations (potentially a lot of work).  Might be a good time to review or revise the layout of your forms to be more usable with OCR.

I have also written C# extensions for Kofax Capture.  I would recommend training on this, even though there are some fairly good examples in the documentation, and it comes with the source code for a lot of different extensions right off the bat.  A lot of the samples are in VB.NET or VB6, but you can absolutely use C# for anything in the latest incarnation of Kofax Capture, to the best of my knowledge.  Kofax Support has been helpful to me with this as well.

Comment: Do you happen to know a source for a C#/.NET sample for an Export Connector? The examples are all in VB and supports claims they have none in C#. We'll probably convert one of those VB projects to C# but it would be a great help to have a working example.

Comment: Sorry I don't currently have any working samples I can hand out.  I would keep working with Kofax support.  I'm really sure they had a sample export connector or something which was in C#.  Or maybe one of their free ones had source code included.  I think it was the Text Export connector that had the source included in C#.

Comment: My company has a working Kofax 10.1 Export Connector that is in C#.  I believe it was converted from VB.NET using an automated conversion tool  and then tested.  We now enhance and maintain it in C#.